# Replace CGContextAddLineToPoint with CGContextAddCurveToPoint

Tags: ios, cgcontext, quartz-2d, curve

I have an array of CGPoint values. Now I am doing something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<coveringValuesArray.count; ++i){
    CGPoint nextPoint = [coveringValuesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    nextPoint = [self offsetPoint:nextPoint on:rect.origin];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
}
```

Need to draw this graph with curves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 for(int i=1; i<coveringValuesArray.count; ++i){
        CGPoint nextPoint = [coveringValuesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        nextPoint = [self offsetPoint:nextPoint on:rect.origin];
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(nextPoint.x,nextPoint.y,1,1));
    }
```

Or Can use Bezier Curves

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
CGPoint firstPoint = coveringValuesArray[0];
[path moveToPoint:firstPoint];
for(int i=1; i<coveringValuesArray.count; ++i){
        CGPoint nextPoint = [coveringValuesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        nextPoint = [self offsetPoint:nextPoint on:rect.origin];
        [path addLineToPoint:nextPoint];
 }
[path closePath];
```